# global query parameter for webapi responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, delegatinghandler

I have a restful webapi, and I want to support a queryparameter for searching something like `?q=`

What I thought about doing is using delegatingHandler for changing the response
Basically creating a QueryHandler for each type of Resource

BaseQueryHandler method would look like so

```
HttpResponseMessage IQueryHandler.Query(HttpResponseMessage response, string query)
        {
            httpResponse = response;

            T content;
            if (response.TryGetContentValue(out content))
            {
               response = Request.CreateResponse(Query(content, query));
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Concrete QueryHandler like so

```
  public override Organization Query(Organization content, string query)
    {
        query = query.ToLower();
        var organization = content.ChildOrganizations?.Where(o => o.Name.ToLower().Contains(query));
        return  
    }
```

## UPDATE:

I will definitely have a look at OData.

What I've done so far is to implement my QueryHandler and then use an extension method for searching objects for fields and values

```
public static IEnumerable<T> LikeOr<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string columnName, string searchTerm)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> words =
                searchTerm.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.Length > 1);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                    sb.Append(" || ");

                sb.Append(words.First().IsNumeric() ? $"{columnName} = @{i}" : $"{columnName}.Contains(@{i})");
            }

            var intSearch = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(words.First(), out intSearch))
                return source.Where(sb.ToString(), intSearch);

            return source.Where(sb.ToString(), words.ToArray());
        }
```

and then using that in my concrete searcHandler implementation like so

```
public override IEnumerable<Organization> Search(IEnumerable<Organization> content, string query)
    {
        var searchTerm = query.Split(':');
        var field = searchTerm[0];
        var term = searchTerm[1];
        var entitites = content.LikeOr(field, term);
        return entitites;
    }
```

(actually found this in another answer regard dynamic.Linq (dont remember the URL, will update when i refind it, to give proper credit)

**Does any of you have a better way of doing this?**

Normally you would properly have the query parameter on all actions, I'd like to NOT have that :)

Comment: If you want to let the client query your data as he wants, have you looked at [OData](https://odata.github.io/)?

Comment: You should definately take a look at [OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint).